# Removing html, javascript etc from POST

Tags: php

I got a simple script which I'm using to POST one world and then to display it with lines from list_of_files.txt. Just noticed that I can POST JavaScript, PHP and Html. How I strip this?

```
$files=file('list_of_files.txt');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){ 
    foreach($files as $list)
    {
        $extension = $_POST['extension'];
        echo trim($list) . trim($extension);
        echo "</div>";
    }
}else{ 
?>
```

Comment: Look into `htmlspecialchars()` and `strip_tags()` manual pages

Answer (score 4, accepted):

strip_tags($str) (http://php.net/manual/de/function.strip-tags.php) will remove *ALL* HTML tags

Example:

```
name=<strong>Finn</strong>&last_name=<script>alert('XSS');</script>
```

PHP:

```
$normal = $_POST['name']; //<strong>Adam</strong>
$stripped = strip_tags($_POST['name']); //Adam
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)?

> This function tries to return a string with **all NULL bytes, HTML and PHP tags stripped from a given str**. It uses the same tag stripping state machine as the fgetss() function.

if you're looking to output, you can use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

```
The translations performed are:

   '&' (ampersand) becomes '&amp;'
   '"' (double quote) becomes '&quot;' when ENT_NOQUOTES is not set.
   "'" (single quote) becomes '&#039;' (or &apos;) only when ENT_QUOTES is set.
   '<' (less than) becomes '&lt;'
   '>' (greater than) becomes '&gt;'
```